# Why my navbar is not collapsing once the screen res is small?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navbar, I am trying to get the collapse menu on smaller screens, but once the screen is small, the menu just disappears and the only thing you can see there is the navbar-brand.

[a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPEzeL)

here my code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top capilleira-navbar ng-cloak"
     role="navigation"
     ng-controller="MenuController"
     ng-show="displayLogout">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/lines"><img src="/images/logos/logo.png" alt=""></a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a class="hover-nieve" href="#/lines">Sports <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="hover-nieve" href="javascript:void(0);">Poker</a></li>
        <li><a class="hover-nieve" href="javascript:void(0);">Casino</a></li>
        <li><a class="hover-nieve" href="javascript:void(0);">Horses</a></li>
        <li><a class="hover-nieve" href="javascript:void(0);">Info</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input id="search-box" ng-change="broadcastSearchBar()"
                 type="search"
                 ng-model="search"
                 class="search-box"
                 placeholder="Search lines..."/>
          <label for="search-box">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search search-icon"
                  ng-show="!search.length"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove search-icon blue-icon"
                  ng-show="search.length"
                  ng-click="search = ''; broadcastSearchBar()"></span>
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="sideborders"></div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-blue" title="Account Figures"
                  data-placement="bottom"
                  data-template="views/accFiguresModal.html" data-animation="fx-bounce-down"
                  ng-controller="AccountFiguresCtrl" ng-click="displayAccountFigures();"
                  bs-popover data-auto-close="true">Account Figures
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-red" title="Are you sure?" data-placement="bottom"
                  data-template="views/logoutModal.html"
                  data-animation="fx-bounce-down" data-auto-close="1" bs-popover>Log out
                  <i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-lg"></i>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the menu collapses and the "hamburger icon" shows up, only problem is that it's completely white and therefore results invisible.
try adding this to your css, at the end, so you see what I mean:

```
span.icon-bar { background-color: red; }
```

hope this helps.

Comment: actually that is wrong, I am unable to see it by adding that in my css, can you show me that in the codepen I did ?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pvKmQp
You have to shrink the window to see it, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

There are various issues with your markup and codepen..

- You've given the `navbar` 2 id= attributes. That doesn't work!
- You hid the toggle button by adding the `collapse` class
- You didn't include `bootstrap.js` in your codepen so `data-toggle` won't work
- By default the icon-bar of the toggle button is white, so it won't    show up unless your navbar has a background color.

Here's the fix on Bootply http://bootply.com/26LXmNJFbq (Bootstrap is aleady included)